# LSTM accuracy not increasing more than 68%

Tags: classification, lstm, accuracy

I am a newbie in the field of deep learning. I am trying to use LSTM with time series data with more than 300,000 datapoints. The target variable is a class with 7 unique values. I used one-hot encoding to covert it into numerical values. The final dataset looks as follows.

```
                      0    1    2    3    4    5    6   
datetime                                                                                 
1970-01-09 03:32:31  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
1970-01-09 03:40:59  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  
1970-01-09 04:14:28  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
1970-01-09 13:07:18  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
1970-01-09 15:44:40  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

My question is that after looking at multiple examples, I came up with the following LSTM but my training accuracy is not increasing more than 68%. Do you have any recommendations about what changes can help? I have tried changing the look_back value, epochs, batch size, number of hidden nodes, layers, etc. The accuracy changes only slightly with these modifications.

```
   X_train, y_train = preprocess_LSTM(train, look_back)
   X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (len(X_train), look_back, outputs))

   model = Sequential()
   model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(input_nodes, outputs)))
   model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(outputs, activation='softmax'))
   model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

   # fit network
   X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
   y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
   model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
   # evaluate model
   _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128)
   print (accuracy)
```

Comment: Try it with only one dense layer. If that doesn’t work, try other models, collect more data, or develop better features. But also note that there doesn’t appear to be any reason you *should* get more than this accuracy.

Comment: Could it be a problem that for some of the datapoints, my timestamp is the same but target variable has a different value? Do you have any suggestions on how we can deal with events occurring simultaneously?

Comment: You’ll need to explain what the data represent. If the events aren’t mutually exclusive, then using softmax is a mistake, but it’s impossible to know based on what information is available.

Comment: The data represents Memory resources for job arriving in the cloud. Since there are only 7 unique values for it, I am using classification. Since the jobs can arrive simultaneously, some of my timestamps are repeated.

Comment: Softmax supposes that the events are mutually exclusive. That means your model won’t be able to reflect simultaneous arrivals.